# How to pass columns of data frame as arguments to a function in a for loop or apply function

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, plyr

I want to pull api data on rental listings for multiple cities and areas using a nifty functional called rentals from craigr package.
if  the name of a city is placed in quotes as the location argument (see code below) and a second argument for area name is added, it will return a number of most recent listings from that region.
for instance, the code below will return the latest 100 regions from the lac area of losangeles as a dataframe.

```
    Billy<-craigr::rentals(location = "losangeles", area = "lac", max_results = 100)
```

The default argument for area = "all". This will return all of the neighborhood listings for the city.
So if I pass a loop of cities like below, I will get a list of dataframes for each city passed.

```
    CityList <- c("losangeles","chicago").
DataPull.df <- lapply(CityList,function(x){craigr::rentals(location = x, area = "all", max_results = 100) })
```

What I want to do is create a dataframe with two columns of city (location) and region(area) pass each column to the respective argument in the function rentals and get a dataframe in return for each city and region passed to the rental function. In the example below, I want three dataframes for three regions of LA.

```
    locations <-c("losangeles","losangeles","losangeles")
    area <-c("wst","sfv","lac")
    passdata<- as.data.frame(locations,area)
```

The following code produces an error because I don't understand how to pass these arguments to an apply function, but hopefully the problem is well understood. Thanks for any help. How do I pass columns of a dataframe as quoted character strings as arguments of a function?

```
    FinalDataPull.df <- lapply(passdata,function(x){craigr::rentals(location = x[1], area = x[2], max_results = 100) })
```

Comment: `lapply(seq(nrow(passdata)), function(x) craigr::rentals (location = passdata[x,1], area = rownames(passdata)[x], max_results = 100)`

Comment: alternatively, `mapply(function(x,y)craigr::rentals(location=x, area=y, max_results=100), locations, area)`

Comment: Thank you so much Adam. You solved my problem!!